# Firebase notification from PHP server

Tags: php, android, firebase

I am using FCM (Android) and it is working fine from - sending notification directly from compose of firebase console and also when I test my PHP script it gives the correct output:

```
{"multicast_id":5817973274009447959,"success":3,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1541837259627974%6102bf30f9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1541837259627976%6102bf30f9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1541837259628246%6102bf30f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

But when the notification is not getting delivered through the server. Meaning when I push request to firebase through my PHP script it is not delivering the notification despite the correct postman output. Please help!

Comment: need more infomation

Comment: I have setup the firebase with my adroid app correctly. When i send notification from my firebase console it is getting delivered. I wrote all relevant services in android. I store my token via my android activity into my MySQL database along with email. Then I try to get the stored token of my mobile from the mysql via a PHP script and curl operations push it to FCM API URL. When I run the PHP script it is giving the correct output (as listed) but the notification isnt getting delivered. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: The php code that fcm sends, and your application is receiving notifications in the background